# WxPython DataViewListCtrl item data

Tags: wxpython

I'm using DataViewListCtrl and i add itemswith

> AppendItem(["test123"])

How can i add data associated with each item?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I know, but there should be an answer.

`AppendItem(["test123", "data for second column", "third column", "etc..."])`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that control as of yet, but it appears us AssociateModel to associate groups of class objects to the control. See the wxPython demo for more information. Personally, I prefer to use ObjectListView, a wrapper for the generic wx.ListCtrl. It works much more simply.

You can read more about that here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/